# Carregar scripts externos em modal sendo carregada via ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5, twitter-bootstrap

Por padrão,eu tenho um arquivo de configuração de vários plugins e ações do meu sistema

Um simples exemplo é o uso de tooltip:

```
$(".bn-tooltip").tooltip({
    track: true
});
```

Datepicker:

```
$('.bn-datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
});
```

Faço isso por que quando vou utilizar em qualquer parte do sistema, basta eu chamar a classe que tenho ali setada.

Pois bem, acontece que quando eu carrego via `ajax` minhas modais, ele não reconhece essas "configurações" e eu tenho que passar dentro da página da modal os mesmo códigos que já tenho, ou colocar o arquivo de `config.js` na `modal`...

Existe alguma solução elegante para não precisar inserir toda a vez que for usar modal os mesmos códigos ou inserir sempre os arquivos de `script`?

Comment: Não entendi bem, mas parece que o problema é você tentar aplicar os plugins a elementos da página antes deles existirem. Se for isso mesmo, não tem necessidade de incluir scripts novamente, apenas inicializar os plugins no momento certo para cada elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A maneira elegante é colocando uma `section` para Scripts no Layout da Modal:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Assim, para cada arquivo de *View* que não seja uma *Partial*, basta chamar as *Views* com a seguinte declaração ao final delas:

```
@section scripts 
{
    <script>
        $(".bn-tooltip").tooltip({
            track: true
        });

        $('.bn-datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: mas o meu problema é quando são partial views :/

Comment: Não vou nem colocar como resposta, mas você pode colocar a tag de `<script>` dentro da *Partial*. Não é nada elegante, mas funciona.

Comment: por isso mesmo que fiz a pergunta, eu faço de 2 formas, ou a tag <script com o código dentro, ou com src para um arquivo externo

Comment: Neste caso o arquivo externo é uma boa.

Comment: dos males o pior kkk